# formula to minutes and seconds down into total amount in seconds

Tags: excel

I am looking a formula for excel that minus a feild called end time by field start time and answer will show as the total amount of seconds the calls lasted.

For example i have call that ended 04:04:35 and started at 03:51:51 and i need to how many seconds that would be in total and instead of working by calucator would like to know if there fourmula to do it

thanks 
simon

Answer (score 4):

The easiest is to set the two cells as time (hh:mm:ss) then subtract them.

Put the result on a new cell, formatted as a number and multiply the result by 86400.

See [this post](http://www.excelforum.com/showthread.php?t=573306&p=1695811&viewfull=1#post1695811) for the explanation

EDIT: the final cell has to be in number format, something like this:

```
                      A         B             C
 Cells        1    03:51:51  04:04:35  =(B1-A1)*86400
 Cell format:      hh:mm:ss  hh:mm:ss       number
```